# How to include Cocos2dx UI library in Android project

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to include one of the UI classes in my cocos2dx project.

In my scene class I have:

```
 #include "CocosGUI.h"
```

It compiles fine for iOS, but when I try to use the command line to compile for Android I get the following error:

```
fatal error: CocosGUI.h: No such file or directory
```

I understand it's because it can't find the library. I've been trying to find the right one to add but haven't had any luck.

I've added:

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_ui_static
```

and

```
$(call import-module,extensions)
$(call import-module,ui)
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

I'm using cocos2dx v3.0

Answer (score 7):

Change your import to "ui/CocosGUI.h". I am using 3.3.

You don't need to edit your Android.mk's `import-module` or `import-add-path` lines, or your `build-cfg.json`, all you need to do is change the specific headers to this generic one.

Comment: Great! You saved my 8hrs! I am using 3.3 too

Comment: Same here, Xcode accepts it without the "ui/" but eclipse does not

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by getting the right libraries to compile in the make file.

Here is what I added:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ... \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos/ui \
```

AND ADDING THESE LINES IN THE RIGHT SECTIONS

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocostudio_static
$(call import-module,editor-support/cocostudio)
```

Comment: Based on `LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES`, this looks like its cocos2dx 2.x? The other answer deals with 3.x.